# Trying to integrate Coda Hale Metrics in spring boot, not seing the metrics in /metrics

Tags: spring-boot, codahale-metrics

I have followed the indication that adding the coda hale metrics library into the classpath would automatically autoconfigure the metrics.

That works, I get the injected metricRegistry bean.

However, how to I expose these new metrics in the /metrics endpoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way it's supposed to work. Codahale has some metric types that do not map to Spring Boot ones, so you are supposed to use the Codahale native APIs for reporting once you start collecting metrics that way. Boot is only providing the service abstraction for Gauge and Counter at that point.

UPDATE: Spring Boot also adds Codahale metrics to the /metrics endpoint since 1.2.0 (see `MetricRegistryMetricReader`).

Comment: but what is this sentence suppose to mean in the spring boot documentation? It does hint that there is some level of integration.

"Users can create Coda Hale metrics by prefixing their metric names with the appropriate type (e.g. histogram.*, meter.*)."

Comment: It means that metrics of type histogram and meter (native Codahale types) can be created by appending to the Spring Boot metrics services. We can clarify the docs a bit if you want to make a suggestion.

Comment: As far as I've understood the documentation, you can inject GaugeService and CounterService. So you can create metrics of those types. But how can you "append" to the spring boot metrics services. I can hardly imagine that you add a histogram with help of the GaugeService?

Comment: Why not? You just send a measurement with a name in "histogram.*" (gauge is better than counter semantically, but I think both work). That's what it says in the docs (admittedly perhaps not clearly enough).

Comment: ok great! thanks. The docs could be a little more explicit i agree.

Comment: I also think that documentation does require some clarification (or example) on this

Comment: Why is the prefix needed? Does it have any semantics? As far as I see it, it's possible without the prefix as well and Spring-Boot will still export the data in the /metrics endpoint.

Comment: The prefix is a signal to Spring Boot to send the metric to Codahale, so yes it's needed if that's what you want to happen.

Answer (score 4):

There's some integration magic accomplished by http://www.ryantenney.com/metrics-spring/ that wires codahale metrics into the actuator `/health` endpoint.

With this dependency included,

```
compile 'com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:3.0.0-RC2'
```

you can "enableMetrics" in your application configuration

```
@EnableMetrics
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    ...
```

This allows you to time each request with the `@timed` annotation:

```
@Timed
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Foo foo() {
    ...
```

and to have your other interactions with `MetricRegistry` aggregate into the actuator `/health` endpoint.

I've put together an example application which implements this integration:

https://github.com/benschw/consul-cluster-puppet/tree/master/demo

and written a more in depth tutorial here:
http://txt.fliglio.com/2014/10/spring-boot-actuator/

Comment: Actually Spring Boot also adds Codahale metrics to the /metrics endpoint on its own since 1.2.0 (see `MetricRegistryMetricReader`).

Answer (score 1):

I update a metrics histogram using spring-boot like this:

```
        gauge.submit("histogram." + name + ".millis", durationMillis);
```