# Using @Timed in service method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics

I'm working with Spring Boot, and I want to annotate some of my `@Service` methods with `@Timed` so I could view their statistics calling the metrics endpoint.

I've read from the Spring documentation that is can use dropwizard registry, but I can't find any example in which it uses dropwizar annotations.

How can I configure my Spring Boot app so each method annotated with `@Timed` automatically publishes its statistics using the build-in Spring actuator module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at: http://www.ryantenney.com/metrics-spring/

Seems that you need to include that library if you want to use Spring with Metrics 3.0 / 3.1.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I've included the dependency, but my service method doesn't appear when I call /metrics endpoint

Comment: Have you taken a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571282/trying-to-integrate-coda-hale-metrics-in-spring-boot-not-seing-the-metrics-in